# Intellisense in Intellij with spark libraries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I've created a Spark project in IntelliJ and Intellsense (code completation) doesnt't work. It works for standard Scala libraries, but not for Spark. Any ideas what can be wron? (I've already done Invalidate Caches and restart)

built.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
```

Comment: Where do you have `build.sbt`? Can you list the files under the top-level directory of the project? The name in your question is `builT.sbt`, but should rather be `builD.sbt` (note the letter D).

Comment: It's the Coursera Scala Spark project. I've created a main module (c4_Spark, and under it, week2/stackoverflow and here all the project structure (src/, build.sbt). So the full path is: c4_spark/week2/stackoverflow/buidl.sbt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build.sbt needs to be under the root folder of the project .

Comment: And there's no other way to create a different path structure? with multiprojects?

Comment: You can create nested project but also in this way each project need build.sbt under the root folder of the project